# Jquery access Slider Tabs From outside of Tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using [Jquery Slider Tabs](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/) and wondering how to open tab contents via link outside the tab.

Below is my html structure,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test specs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/styles/jquery.sliderTabs.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/jquery.sliderTabs.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var tabs = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySliderTabs">
  <!-- Unordered list representing the tabs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#canyon">The Grand Canyon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#taj">The Taj Mahal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bigben">Big Ben</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Afterwards, include the div panels representing the panels of our slider -->
  <div id="canyon">
    <h3>The Grand Canyon</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="taj">
    <h3>The Taj Mahal</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="bigben">
    <h3>Big Ben</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ess">
<p><a href="#bigben">Big Ben Tab</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On click of `<p><a href="#bigben">Big Ben Tab</a></p>` i need to open third tab. I've added the same in [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vevas/1/)

Did anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test specs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/styles/jquery.sliderTabs.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/jquery.sliderTabs.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var tabs = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
      $('#bigbenlink').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#bigbenslider').click();
      });
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySliderTabs">
  <!-- Unordered list representing the tabs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#canyon">The Grand Canyon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#taj">The Taj Mahal</a></li>
    <li><a id="bigbenslider" href="#bigben">Big Ben</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Afterwards, include the div panels representing the panels of our slider -->
  <div id="canyon">
    <h3>The Grand Canyon</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="taj">
    <h3>The Taj Mahal</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
  <div id="bigben">
    <h3>Big Ben</h3>
    <!-- rest of the panel content -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ess">
<p><a id="bigbenlink" href="#bigben">Big Ben Tab</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next time use Jsfiddle. I rewrote this 3 times in Jsbin, which clears the screen if you try to select everything, until I gave up and rewrote it here...